# Maven Gatling 3.0.2 - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

When I run "mvn clean gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=package.SimpleSim", I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
    at io.gatling.core.cli.CommandLineConstant.<init>(CommandLineConstant.scala:19)
    at io.gatling.app.cli.CommandLineConstants$.<init>(CommandLineConstants.scala:22)
    at io.gatling.app.cli.CommandLineConstants$.<clinit>(CommandLineConstants.scala)
    at io.gatling.app.cli.ArgsParser$$anon$1.<init>(ArgsParser.scala:30)
    at io.gatling.app.cli.ArgsParser.<init>(ArgsParser.scala:28)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:46)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:39)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
```

I tried removing a lot of dependencies with only Gatling Highchart and Gatling Plugin remaining. It stills throw the same error.

The funny thing is I copy many code from a working project and the project is still running properly now.

I am not sure why this is happening in the new project...

The pom:

```
  <parent>
    <artifactId>abc-pom</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.abc.def</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <gatling.version>3.0.3</gatling.version>
    <gatling-plugin.version>3.0.2</gatling-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <configFolder>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/gatling_conf</configFolder>
              <runMultipleSimulations>true</runMultipleSimulations>
              <includes>
                <simulationClass>package.SimpleSim</simulationClass>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The script:

```
package package.scalability_test

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class SimpleSim extends Simulation {
    val httpProtocolBuilder = http.baseUrl("http://www.google.com")
    val scenarioBuilder = scenario("Get").exec(http("Get_Request")
        .get("/"))

    setUp(
        scenarioBuilder.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1) during(60 seconds))
    ).protocols(httpProtocolBuilder)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that settings `<sourceDirectory>src/main</sourceDirectory>` is correct? I have my doubts..

Comment: @khmarbaise I am pretty sure it is correct. My old pom has the same thing and everything runs fine. I just commented that piece of code out as well. The error is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually due to the `<parent></parent>` tag. This is a project within a larger project. Somehow, inheriting the parent pom causes some conflicts which resulted in this issue.

My solution was to remove the `<parent>` tag. But, the correct solution could be to actually figure out which dependency is causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

First check your all Scala version in your classpath `mvn dependency:tree`, then override with compatible Scala version with your Gatling version